# Паттерн проектирования Future .Net C#

Tags: c#

В книге Марка Гранда "Шаблоны проектирования" описан паттерн проектирования Future. Кто-нибудь использовал данный паттерн в C# и может объяснить в чем его суть?

Comment: совершенно верно, кто-то знает. это намёк на то, что надо бы сформулировать вопрос так, как полагается.

Comment: Книга Марка Гранда шаблоны проектирования

Comment: @ЮрійСомик вы думаете все вокруг знают кто такой Марк Гранд и читали его книгу?

Comment: @ЮрійСомик, я поправил ваш вопрос, так чтобы он был понятен без чтения комментариев и отформатировал по правилам SO. Надеюсь вы не в претензии, я старался чтобы суть осталось прежней?

Comment: `Task<T>` изначально в .NET назывался `Future<T>`. Именно он, по сути, является реализацией этого паттерна. А суть в том, что создаётся задача, которая когда-то в _будущем_ вернёт результат.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а почему не ответом?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Суть паттерна заложена в его названии: future - будущее. Он означает, что создаётся задача, которая когда-либо в будущем вернёт результат.

Реализацией этого паттерна в .NET является класс [`Task<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx). Что любопытно, изначально, на стадии разработки, он назывался `Future<T>`, но позже был переименован. Тем не менее, артефакты остались: например, файл [Future.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs) в исходном коде.

Для подробного ознакомления смотрите документацию по библиотеке [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx), в частности, [Futures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963556.aspx).

В современном C# есть ещё более удобные средства для работы с фьючерами - [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh191443(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо вы мне очень помогли